# WPF: Bindings - Object not updated

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a an object which is set to the DataContext in a Window. I have textboxes in the window which are bound to the properties on the object. There seems to be a delay however before the properties on the object are updated.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtPropertyOne" Text="{Binding Path=PropertyOne,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
```

If I change the values in a few textboxes then quickly try to access the properties to which they map, sometimes there are changes which aren't reflected in the properties of the object. I thought that was what the PropertyChanged UpdateSourceTrigger was supposed to take care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I change the values in a few
>   textboxes then quickly try to access
>   the properties to which they map

I can interpret this statement in two ways:

1. You're trying to access the values on a background thread. In that case, you may be accessing the properties before the UI thread has had a chance to do its thing.
2. You're using a separate message on the UI thread to check the values. Bindings are updated at a priority lower than `Send` and `Normal`. So if your message is priority `Send` or `Normal` it will be processed before any pending binding updates.

If this doesn't answer your question, please clarify what you mean by "quickly trying to access the properties".

Comment: That's what I was thinking. With the object being the DataContext, I'm accessing it from a BackgroundWorker, which may be why it doesn't get chance to update. I'll try calling UpdateSource on the bindings before starting the BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule of WPF Databinding is simple:

- The target property must be a
  dependency property, and you're
  already correct, it's bound to Text
  property of TextBox.
- The source property can be a CLR
  object (other than any derived WPF's
  DependencyObject), but the object
  must employ or implement its own
  INotifyPropertyChanged.

Have you you already implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on your object?

Comment: All of the object's properties fire NotifyPropertyChanged events. I think Kent Boogart might have nailed it with accessing from another thread before the UI has updated the object's properties.

Comment: Yes, but are sure your objects have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface? Kent Boogart answer touches different view and his answer is different than mine.

Comment: Just a comment on point two: the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation matters _only_ if Echilon is doing clrObject.PropertyOne = "some value" and wants the TextBox to change its text; the point is valid only if you are doing two way binding.